# 301 Redirect not working in some cases

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've made a few changes to my URL structure. Here is my htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /top100 http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /monthlytop10 http://www.example.com/monthlytop
Redirect 301 /top100/Hardwell http://www.example.com/top100/hardwell
Redirect 301 /top100/Armin%20van%20Buuren http://www.example.com/top100/armin-van-buuren
Redirect 301 /top100/David%20Guetta http://www.example.com/top100/david-guetta
```

This works for the first 2 cases but doesn't work for the rest. It redirects `www.example.com/top100/Armin%20van%20Buuren` to `www.example.com/Armin%20van%20Buuren`

If I remove the first line in the htaccess file, it doesn't redirect at all and gives a 404 error. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `Redirect` directive doesn't support regex. Use `RedirectMatch` instead to match exactly what you want:

```
RedirectMatch 302 "^/top100/?$" /
RedirectMatch 302 "^/monthlytop10/?$" /monthlytop
RedirectMatch 302 "^/top100/Hardwell/?$" /top100/hardwell
RedirectMatch 302 "^/top100/Armin van Buuren/?$" /top100/armin-van-buuren
RedirectMatch 302 "^/top100/David Guetta/?$" /top100/david-guetta
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for links with `%20`

Comment: Use a new browser to test this. With these rules when I open `/top100/Armin%20van%20Buuren` it became `/top100/armin-van-buuren`